# Ebean Finder: find items NOT matching criteria

Tags: java, playframework-2.1, ebean

I would like to search items with Ebean in Play Framework 2.1 using *Finder* and find the one that are *not* mathing the criteria. Some kind of `left join a_table t ... where t.id is null` (or maybe a `where not exists`).

I could not find how to do that by reading Ebean's API. Google does not help either.

Is it possible to do it?
If yes, how?

To give an exemple, let's say I have persons that have year-subscriptions. I would like to retrieve the persons that do not have a current subscription.

```
public class Person {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Subscription> subscriptions;
}
```

Thanks!

Alban

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used `com.avaje.ebean.Query`.

For my example:

```
String q = "find * fetch subscriptions "
         + "where subscriptions.startDate > :today "
         + "   or subscriptions.endDate < :today "
         + "   or subscriptions.id is null";
Query<Person> query = Ebean.createQuery(Person.class, q);
query.setParameter("today", LocalDate.now());
return query.findList();
```

And it seems to work.